# Is it acceptable to use "Just wondering" as a question?

Tags: grammar, punctuation, question-mark

I often find myself writing sentences such as:
"I am wondering if the landlord replied to you yet?"

And I always end up removing the question mark and rephrasing the sentence. In speech it is easy to inflect such a sentence so as to infer that it is a question, but in reality "I am wondering" is a statement and I feel it should not have a question mark when written down.

So is it acceptable to use "I am wondering" as a question?

Comment: Written language is a communication tool. According to most attempts at codifying the rules of writing English, question marks should only be used where a question is written, and not just a statement [citation needed]. In speech, the raising of the voice at the end of the sentence can be used to give a questioning tone to a statement. The most obvious way to turn this into writing is with a question mark. It would be widely understood as such. Is it acceptable? Well, it depends on who is doing the accepting or rejecting. This is probably therefore "opinion based".

Comment: You sentence is closer to a question than to a statement, so I'd use that mark. Coffee? We only see that sentence as a question because of the mark. With your sentence floating by itself, it's clear you want an answer. As part of an email, you could state "I am wondering" and go on to ask "Then would you mind, while you're away, if I ask the landlord myself?"

Comment: Your title shows your own fix: "Just wondering, did the landlord reply to you yet?"

Comment: Using wonder like that makes it an indirect question. Search this site for wonder indirect question. Or Google it.

Comment: It *is* a statement. The terminal mark of interrogation, when used, is not meant to signal that the sentence is a question, rather, an informal way of the same thing as what "I am wondering" expresses.

Answer (score 1):

It is acceptable to say it but it would be more conversational in tone and style so it would be NOT be appropriate for a formal document.

Phrasing the question in that fashion might be perceived as being diplomatic, perhaps in a situation where you are asking someone for something you know they have not done!  "I am just wondering if you go around to writing that report..." but there may be an inference of an implied but subtle criticism.

Comment: While "I was wondering do you have any beans left?" is debatable, you can always apply the slight change (which is invisible in spoke form) "I was wondering, do you have any beans left?" or even "I was wondering -- do you have any beans left?" Both are formally correct English.